# Core Data setValue seem to overWrite previous values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Trying to learn `core data` and get stuck on this thing where I set the data, but when I try to fetch it, only the last element is returned. I have a feeling this is because `setValue` overWrites the previous values.

```
func setData(data: People) {

    let enmployeeEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "EmployeesCoreData", in: context)
    let employee = NSManagedObject(entity: enmployeeEntity!, insertInto: context)

    for i in 0...data.people.count - 1 {
        employee.setValue(data.people[i].name, forKey: "name")
        print(data.people[i].name)
    }
}
```

The `print` gives me all ten elements, so at least I know that they're there.

Then when I try to `fetch` the data all I get is the very last element of `data.people[i].name`.

```
func fetchMyData() {

    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EmployeesCoreData")
        let result = try context.fetch(request)

        print(result.count) //Returns 1
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            let myDataName = data.value(forKey: "name") as! String
             print("", myDataName)
        }
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        print(nserror)
        }
}
```

Any idea why only the last `element` is shown? Let me know if you need to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one instance of your entity in setData, change the loop to

```
for i in 0...data.people.count - 1 {
    let employee = NSManagedObject(entity: enmployeeEntity!, insertInto: context)
    employee.setValue(data.people[i].name, forKey: "name")
    print(data.people[i].name)
}
```